# How can I set up Perl Cgi in Nginx on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, nginx, fastcgi

I had a Nginx/php server running in linux and was successfully using the widely available  [cgi-bin.php script](http://pastebin.com/D0dZHbRc) to run awstats.

After switching back to Windows and correctly configuring Nginx, Php and installing Strawberry Perl, the script will not run, it just says "Page Not Found".

I realize that this is caused caused by the `is_executable` switch in the  php script, but if I remove the switch, the request will sit there doing nothing until php times out, giving a 504 error.

Here is the part of my nginx conf file that does the cgi-bin folder (php-cgi is listening on 127.0.0.1:9000)

```
                # Configure /cgi-bin/scripts to go through php-fastcgi
        location ~ ^/cgi-bin/.*\.(cgi|pl|py|rb) {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   cgi-bin.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    C:/wemp/cgi-bin.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        /cgi-bin/cgi-bin.php;
        fastcgi_param   X_SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/wemp/cgi-bin$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   X_SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;

        #fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        #fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        #fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        #fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
        #fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        #fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
        #fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        #fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        #fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        #fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        #fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        #fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        #fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        #fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        #fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
}
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, I would suggest looking at uwsgi (or whatever server you fancy) + psgi too/instead.

Comment: Check the permissions on the file.